# How to show own photo in SMS conversation?

Tags: sms

How can I show my own photo profile icon in SMS conversations? I cannot find where to set it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your device and what app you are using. On my Droid 1 running Froyo if I add my own cell # to my contacts the default messaging app uses the avatar that is set with that contact entry.  if you add this it may take a little while for everything to sync up and for the pic to begin to display. In Handcent SMS you can set custom contact specific avatars.

Comment: Your tip worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

In my case Matt's solution didn't work, so I found this solution on http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=3a41f790937732e1&hl=en

---

This is caused by a few different problems.

1. If you go into `Settings -> About phone -> Status` and the `My Phone Number` section is **`Unknown`** or **not your number**, then your problem is that the phone doesn't know which contact to use for you.
2. If your number is in there and correct then it may not know *which* contact to use, if you have **multiple contacts with the same number**.

## Unknown Number

In the first case (unknown number) you will need to use another handset to change the number. Find someone (possibly on the same network as you) with an iPhone and get them to let you put your SIM card in it, **on the iPhone** go into `Settings -> Phone -> My Number` and then enter your phone number, hit `Okay` and then eject the SIM. Put it back in your phone and it should just work, if not follow onto the next procedure.

## Multiple Matching Contacts

This is easier from gmail, find all the contacts you have with the same number as your phone (with and without country codes) and delete/merge them, if you deleted them create a new contact with your details and avatar in it and save.

After syncing with the mobile your Messaging app should show the correct avatar.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Huawei Ascend g300

Click on your 'Messaging' icon to get a list of your conversations.
Then click on the menu button below your screen, click Settings. You will see a title 'Common Settings' look below Common Settings and there is 'My Picture'. Click 'My Picture' to choose a profile photo from your Gallery or take a photo with your camera. Easy

I found it by accident as I was searching how to add a picture of me. Not having a Profile Picture was driving me insane!!!! lol

Answer (score 0):

I have a droid bionic and I went into my contacts and at the top it says your profile and I filled it out and put my picture in there and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In Handcent, I just found out by exploring, there is a file called "hc_account_picture.png" which gives the picture to the "Me" Contact internally.

/data/data/com.handcent.nextsms/files/hc_account_picture.png

is the full path. just copy the new graphic file here and then restart the phone!!!