# Set your own contact photo on huawei ascend 2?

Tags: photos, huawei-ascend-ii, contact-photo

I've tried *everything*. Saving myself as a contact, and changed the picture. Didn't work. Synced all my google accounts. Didn't work. I'm not even automatically saved in my contacts. I had to save my number, just to get to my voicemail.

Answer (score 1):

### OWN CONTACT AVATAR

To have your own contact avatar appearing, this varies a bit, due to the device being used or the app being used.

What is recommend and should work on any case is that you need to identify yourself to your phone:

- Tap your device "menu" button;
- Tap "Settings";
- Scroll your way to "About phone" and tap it;
- Tap "Status":

  Where it reads "My phone number", you should read your own and up-to-date phone number there, otherwise the phone doesn't know who you are and cannot use any avatar.

A solution to allow you to apply your up-to-date phone number at the mentioned menu, or a solution to have your contact being retrieved from Google with an avatar, has already been mentioned here concerning the Avatar for the SMS conversation, but equally applies to your situation:

[How to show own photo in SMS conversation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5454/16265), specially the [answer from Protron](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/20879/16265).

---

### CONTACTS AVATAR

Usually the contact photo is the user's avatar, if the contact has a Google Account.

To apply a photo or change the existing one, you have to:

1. Open the "Contacts" app;
2. Scroll your way to the desired contact and long tap it;
3. Tap over "Edit Contact" from the popup menu;
4. Tap over the existent picture or over the picture square that if empty shows a `+` sign;
5. Select either "Take photo" or "Select photo from Gallery" to apply the new photo;
6. After selected, tap "Done" to actually save the changes.

By now your contact should have the new photo applied to it.

---

Official Android Support Page for Contacts Management:

- [Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) - Editing contact details](http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168480&topic=29774&ctx=topic)

Comment: Can I do that for my OWN contact? I don't even have an option for myself...

Comment: @Patrice Sorry, I misread your question at first. Added information at the top of my answer concerning the "own contact avatar" situation.